# Configure Tasker as alarm for date and time

Tags: tasker

Could someone be so kind as to show me how to set [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to play a melody selected by myself when 5 June 2016 @ 10 PM is reached. I would like to be able to set the sound file to play, perhaps in a loop. Thanks.

Comment: Bit related: [Play songs randomly and endlessly](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135542)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start having us write a new Tasker profile every day (kidding :), let me give you some help to help yourself: My site holds some [Tasker Graphs](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_950) showing you what conditions and tasks are to be found where. So based on that, here's what you'd have to do.

#### The profile

- **Condition:**

  1. Time › set the time you want this profile to be active
  2. Date › pick your date here
- **Task:** Media › MusicPlay › select your music file

Pretty basic stuff. Below the graphs you can also find a list with [Tasker Tutorials](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_900) – recommended reading :)

#### Notes

- *Tasker* always connects multiple conditions per AND – so it's always "condition-1 AND condition-2".
- When creating a new profile, after having chosen your first condition *Tasker* will immediately continue asking you for the task(s). So complete those first, save the new profile, then long-tap (tap-and-hold) the first condition. This will open a context menu from which you can chose to e.g. add another condition or add an exit-task
- You cannot have multiple conditions of the same type for the same profile. So if you want e.g. the same task executed at two different times, you have to create two profiles; but when creating the second profile, you can simply pick the task created for the first (or any other) profile from a drop-down.

Comment: One more thing: if I want the music to stop, how do I then do that? Closing tasker won't do it, and I cannot see when I long press the home screen the actual app being used to play the music, so I cannot close that app to stop playing the music. Thanks.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between a condition and a context? Thanks.

Comment: About that of a beer and an ale :) Take the two terms as synonym. I've picked up the term "condition" some time in the past (I'm using *Tasker* for more than 5 years already), but the official term is "context" AFAIK. As for stopping the music: That's why I've linked the graphs. Find the "StopPlaying" (or similar) action in *Media* section, make it another task. Then e.g. create a shortcut on your desktop (pick "Tasker", then pick the task) so you can trigger that manually – or simply assign it to another context (e.g. for 5 min later).

Comment: Thank you for your help, that helps a lot. I also see that tasker lets you create more than one profile, each with one or more contexts/conditions associated with them and with one or more tasks for each of these condition sets. Profiles can be enabled/disabled separately. Makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. And there's also our fine [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) which I can recommend to look at :)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what to do with the *Music Stop* task, I couldn't figure out how to create the desktop shortcut. Perhaps you can help me with it?

Comment: See the user guide: [Tasker: Task / Shortcut Widgets](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/app_widgets.html)